# (EDITED) Android peer to peer Wifi Direct Image Receiving issue

Tags: android, image, sockets, p2p, wifi-direct

I am connecting two devices using p2p wifi direct. I have successfully sent a text message from one device to another but when it comes to sending an image I'm stuck. I tried to encode the image and decode on another side but right now the image is being sent successfully, however on the receiving end it doesn't show any image but the specific folder is being created, but when I open the image through the File Manager, it says "File format not supported" and the image doesn't open. The image has a size of 2.92KB.

One more thing I want to ask is how can I send to specific device, I've tried to put the receiving device's Inet address but it doesn't work for me.

Here is my code

For server side

```
    public class ServerClass extends Thread {
        Socket socket;
        ServerSocket serverSocket;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                sendReceive = new SendReceive(socket);
                sendReceive.start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

   public class SendReceive extends Thread {
        private Socket socket;
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private OutputStream outputStream;   
        private DataInputStream dataInputStream;
        int length;
        byte[] Bbytes;

        public SendReceive(Socket sckt) {
            socket = sckt;

            try {
                inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int bytes;

            while (socket != null) {
                try {

                    dataInputStream=new DataInputStream(inputStream);
                    length=dataInputStream.readInt();
                    Bbytes=new byte[length];
                    dataInputStream.readFully(Bbytes,0,Bbytes.length);



                    bytes = inputStream.read(Bbytes);

                    handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, 
                   Bbytes).sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

      //sending images
        public void writeImageData(byte[] bytes){
            try {

                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream=new 
               DataOutputStream(outputStream);
                dataOutputStream.writeInt(bytes.length);
                dataOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

The client side

```
    public class ClientClass extends Thread {
        Socket socket;
        String hostAdd;

        public ClientClass(InetAddress hostAddress) {
            hostAdd = hostAddress.getHostAddress();
            socket = new Socket();

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostAdd, 8888), 700);
                sendReceive = new SendReceive(socket);
                sendReceive.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

To send image to client and I am getting this toast as successful

```
      public class SendImageClient extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... voids) {

            try {

                sendReceive.writeImageData(voids[0]);

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image sent", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }
    }
```

The handler for receive message and reading it

```
         Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
          @Override
          public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuff = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                  Bitmap bitmap= 
                 BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(readBuff,0,readBuff.length);
                 imageView22.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                 saveImage(bitmap);
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    //to save image in device
    private void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap){

        String root= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir= new File(root+"/saved_images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator= new Random();
        int n=10000;
        n=generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname="Image-"+n+".jpg";
        File file=new File(myDir,fname);
        if(file.exists()){
            file.delete();
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "image saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Lastly the send button

```
          btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
          drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
          bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
         imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new 
         ByteArrayOutputStream();
         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, byteArrayOutputStream);
         byte[] array = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

         SendImageClient sendImageClient = new SendImageClient();
         sendImageClient.execute(array);

            }
        });
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thank you in advance.